# Unable to call a function with a reference to a type implementing a trait

Tags: rust, traits, ownership, borrowing

I am having some trouble to understand how to work with Traits and ownerships. The following example works:

```
struct X([u8; 4]);

impl X {
   pub fn get(&self, n: usize) -> u8 {
       self.0[n]
   }
}

fn f1(x: &X) {
    println!("{}", x.get(1));
    f2(&x);
}

fn f2(x: &X) {
    println!("{}", x.get(2));    
}

fn main() {
    let z1 = X([1u8, 2u8, 3u8, 4u8]);
    f1(&z1);
}
```

But when I try to create a trait (here `XT`) with `get`:

```
trait XT {
  fn get(&self, n: usize) -> u8;
}

struct X([u8; 4]);

impl XT for X {
   fn get(&self, n: usize) -> u8 {
       self.0[n]
   }
}

fn f1<T: XT>(x: &T) {
    println!("{}", x.get(1));
    f2(&x);
}

fn f2<T: XT>(x: &T) {
    println!("{}", x.get(2));    
}

fn main() {
    let z1 = X([1u8, 2u8, 3u8, 4u8]);
    f1(&z1);
}
```

Fails to compile with the following error message:

> the trait `XT` is not implemented for the type `&T`

It works if I change `f2(&x)` to `f2(x)`. My expectation was that replacing the types by the traits, everything will work.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

The problem is that you're trying to pass `&&T` to `f2`.  That means it expects `&T` to implement `XT`, and that's *not* what you said: you said that `T` implements `XT`.

You can modify `f1` to properly express this constraint by using a `where T: XT, for<'a> &'a T: XT` clause, but then you can't call `f1` from `main` because `&X` doesn't implement `XT`.  So you go and add an implementation for *that as well*, and *then* the code works... but honestly, it's easier to just remove that `&` and call `f2(x)` instead.

To put it another way: just because a type implements a trait *does not* mean pointers to that type *also* implement the trait.

Comment: But the confusing thing is that it works fine in the first case. (Disclaimer: I do not have a comprehensive view of Rust, so I might be complete wrong) This looks like a very common scenario: you write some function that take a specific Type and then you realize that you can use them for more things. Therefore you create a Trait and replace (with some syntax) the Type for the Trait in the function definitions. The syntax that makes it works is not very ergonomic.

Comment: @Hernan It works in the first case because `z1` is of type `X`, thus `&z1` is of type `&X`.  When you call `f1`, the compiler infers that `&T = &X` therefore `T = X`.  When you call `f2` with `&x`, it gets `&T = &&X`, therefore `T = &X`, and `&X` doesn't implement `XT`.

Comment: Thanks for the explanation. I get it now. I would argue that making the syntax for traits equal to the syntax for types would be more ergonomic, but I guess I am missing important things about the language.